# Unity3d orientation while in progress

Tags: unity-game-engine

This time a more theoretical question. 
At the moment I got 2 canvases (both disabled) and an method called in "Update()" which is checking whether the screen orientation got changed and therefore en/disabling the specific layout.

So far so good. But now I face the following problem:

Assuming, the user has started any method in portrait mode, displaying its progress to the user. 
But midoperation the user turns the phone to landscape mode, therefore inactivating the portrait-canvas and activating the landscape one.

How would you handle the "handover" of the progress? 
Therefore the user has no "reset" in his layout by changing the orientation midoperation.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Worth mentioning: my two canvases each got the same script attached to it. but each canbas got its specific gameobjects attached to the script. Therefore I don't see a way to extract the script from the canvas

Comment: Maybe you could update the "progress" in `static` variables so they are "shared" between all instances of that script. Or alternatively have the progress updated in a seperate independend script like e.g. `ProgressManager` where both canvases get/set there values from/to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another script that keeps track of the Progress.

Then in your UI progress script (the one that you already have in two game objects for the two layouts), use the `OnEnable` method to update the ui progress. Something like:

```
public Progress progress;

private void OnEnable() 
{
    uiProgress = progress.value;
}
```